# Global Variable Not Getting Value

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am wanting to get the row count from each iteration of my Function and assign it to a variable so I can send the results in an email at the end.  My syntax produced an error of this which says to me the `$rowcount` is never actually being assigned to it?

> Send-MailMessage: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Body'.  The argument is null or empty.  Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

```
#Declaring Global Variable
$myArray = $null
$GoodSyntax = "Select * From tableunknown"
$extractFile = "C:\Test.csv"
$dirName = "C:\Completed\"
$date = Get-Date -f 'MM.dd.yy'

#Call function
Execute-SQLquery 
  if (Execute-SQLquery $GoodSyntax) 

$EmailBody = $myArray | Out-String
send-mailmessage -to "abc123@gmail.com" -from "barkbarksalon123@gmail.com" -Body $EmailBody -BodyAsHtml:$true -subject "Testing Through Powershell"


Function Execute-SQLquery {
    param ($GoodSyntax)

$server = "Server01"
$database = "database01"    
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $QueryString
$command.Connection = $connection
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$rowCount = $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
if ($rowCount -gt 0)
    {
    [System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($dirName)
    $filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) + "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)
    $extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename 
    $DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
    $myArray +=  $rowCount
}
$connection.Close()
}
```

Comment: but since I am assigning $rowCount to my global variable wouldn't that be visible to any piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$rowCount` isn't global ... global variables are listed at the top of your code ... it should read like this ...

```
#Declaring Global Variable
$myArray = $null
$rowCount = 0
$GoodSyntax = "Select * From tableunknown"
...
```

Make sense?

---

**EDIT:**

My bad! I see you are adding `$rowCount` to `$myArray` ... that wasn't clear from your question.

Try this ...

```
#Declaring Global Variable
$rowCountTotal = 0
$GoodSyntax = "Select * From tableunknown"
...
$EmailBody = $rowCountTotal | Out-String
...
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
$rowCountTotal += $rowCount
}
```